# jQuery AJAX request not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm attempting to dynamically load in a shopping cart on page load, which works great in everything other than Internet explorer (tested in version 8 and version 11). The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $(".view_cart, .cart_close_button").click(function () {
            $("#cart_content").toggle();
            $(".view_cart").toggleClass('toggled');
            $(".cart_button").toggleClass('cart_pressed');
            $(".cart_header").toggleClass('show');           
            $(".cart_close_button").toggleClass('show');  
            $(".cart_total_icon").toggleClass('hide');              
            return false;                               
        });        

        $.get("/products/show_cart", function(cart){ // Get the contents of the url cart/show_cart
        $("#cart_content").html(cart); // Replace the information in the div #cart_content with the retrieved data
        });             

    });   

    $(window).load(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){ $('.page_message').fadeOut() }, 4000);
    });

</script>
```

HTML for the cart page (this is very basic at the moment)

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="grid grid-pad">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <span class="page_message green_alert"><strong>Cart cleared.</strong> Your shopping cart has been emptied.</span>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="cart_button">

        <a href="#" class="view_cart" title="View your cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-3x"></i> <span class="cart_header">Your Shopping Cart</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Hide your cart" class="cart_close_button">X</a>

        <div id="cart_content">
            <p>CART STUFF GOES HERE</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Anybody know why IE doesn't want to play ball here? It works if I add the `.get` code into the click function, but that causes a small delay when opening the cart box, which I want to avoid really.

Edited to add page HTML and IE versions.

Comment: wich version of IE are you using? Also post your HTML Code.

Comment: Internet explorer 8 and 11 i've tried it in (so assuming in between versions as well) I've updated the original question. Thanks :-)

Comment: Anyway i think you should refresh the cart each time View Cart is clicked. AS you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/6GVBz/17/ it works on Internet Explorer 10. Can you check the fiddle on your IE?

Comment: can you post too the HTML Response of /products/show_cart?

Comment: @Phx - thanks for the suggestion. Yeah it works fine if i add it to the click event, i'd already tried that but the small delay each time you open the cart put me off a bit... Not sure how to get the HTML response from Internet explorer (F12 options not very clear) but this is it from firebug - <p class="cart_empty">You don't have any items yet.</p> - It's just a basic HTML page.

Comment: No errors on IE? (javascript i mean?)

Comment: Version of jquery? jquery 2.x is not working on IE 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After all the comments i think is a jquery version problem. Just check wich version of jquery you need for IE <=8 and IE >=9. You can use this code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>  
    <script src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>  
<![endif]-->  
<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (!IE)]><!-->  
    <script src="jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>  
<!--<![endif]-->
```

You can check this jsFiddle with diferents versions of IE: http://jsfiddle.net/6GVBz/19/show/

Check this link http://www.impressivewebs.com/loading-different-jquery-version-ie6-8/

Comment: Sorry Phx, didn't see the alert that you had replied again! Thinks has nailed it, thanks very much :-)

Comment: This is a working solution, but it should be enough to load the [jQuery migrate plugin](http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-migrate-plugin) in <=IE9, which is created for exactly this purpose.